# Angular 2 multiple countdown pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, countdown, angular2-directives, countdownlatch

I'm looking to create angular 2/4 countdown pipe.

Of course I can make individual countdowns, but how do I create multiple ones?

I want the following input:

```
<span [time]="unix timestamp here">Countdown will count here</span>
```

for example:

```
<span [time]="1500503492">Countdown will count here</span>
<span [time]="15005034392">Countdown will count here</span>
<span [time]="1500503492">Countdown will count here</span>
```

How can I achieve that all would work no matter how many I have?

What I tried so far is only single countdowns like the following:

```
time = 30;
setInterval(() => {
  this.currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  if (this.time > 0) {
    this.time = this.time - 1;
  }
}, 1000);

{{ time}}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your're looking for a `Component` not a `Pipe` or `Directive`.

This component should do what you want:

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-countdown',
  template: '{{ displayTime }}',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CountdownComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private _time: number;
  private _timing: number = 1000;
  private _interval;

  @Input()
  public set time(value: string | number) {
    this._time = parseInt(value as string, 10);
    this._startTimer();
  }

  @Input()
  public set timing(value: string | number) {
    this._timing = parseInt(value as string, 10);
    this._startTimer();
  }

  @Input()
  public format: string = '{dd} days {hh} hours {mm} minutes {ss} seconds';

  public get delta() {
    let date = new Date();
    return Math.max(0, Math.floor((this._time - date.getTime()) / 1000));
  }

  public get displayTime() {
    let days, hours, minutes, seconds, delta = this.delta, time = this.format;

    days = Math.floor(delta / 86400);
    delta -= days * 86400;
    hours = Math.floor(delta  / 3600) % 24;
    delta -= hours * 3600;
    minutes = Math.floor(delta  / 60) % 60;
    delta -= minutes * 60;
    seconds = delta % 60;

    time = time.replace('{dd}', days);
    time = time.replace('{hh}', hours);
    time = time.replace('{mm}', minutes);
    time = time.replace('{ss}', seconds);

    return time;
  }

  constructor(private _changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._stopTimer();
  }

  private _startTimer() {
    if(this.delta <= 0) return;
    this._stopTimer();
    this._interval = setInterval(() => {
      this._changeDetector.detectChanges();
      if(this.delta <= 0) {
        this._stopTimer();
      }
    }, this._timing);
  }

  private _stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(this._interval);
    this._interval = undefined;
  }
}
```

You can input the time you want to count to as unix timestamp and also define a format in which the countdown should be displayed.

Here's an [**example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/JjhN6G7k7QqKlOOZSRAp?p=preview) using the above component.

Comment: Thanks!. but im getting an error on the countdown after im leaving the current view ( because everything subscribed to is destoryed). How can i destory all the countdown that is not existing anymore? because of the detectChanges

Comment: Updated the code and added a ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook, which stops the timer upon component destruction.

Comment: Awesome. So if I want to stop the counter when it reaches a value, how would I go about it?